# Two Parter! Execute command silently in background when process finishes; Cause terminal background to flash a color

Tags: ssh, putty

I run a fair number of batch processes, and will generally turn my attention to a second monitor/activity while I wait for it to finish. I'd to setup the terminal (For what it's worth mentioning: Putty terminal SSH'd to server) so that the terminal will flash a color to get my attention. I know there is a beep command you can use, but it won't work in this case.

So, in my mind I see this being two parts- both useful separately: (probably...)

- Have a watcher process that detects when a single command has been running a while
- Set background color to flash once or twice once watcher process is triggered.

I have no idea if this is within the realm of possibility, but thought somebody might!

Answer (score 0):

How far would

```
wait; for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo -e "$ESC[41m$ESC[2J"; sleep 0.2; echo -e "$ESC[0m$ESC[2J"; sleep 0.2; done
```

get you? Note that screen contents is lost, and not every terminal emulator recognizes the VT100 console codes.

Comment: I feel like this is on the right track... But you are correct- the VT100 (Which I have just learned a bit about) does not seem to work on any of the environments I would use. Thanks though!